# Radians to degrees with a roundoff value between 0-360 degress

Tags: r, math, degrees, radians

I want to convert radians to degrees with a round off function.
The degrees should come between 0-360 for all the radian values.

Say, the value I want to convert is 300(in radians)

So,

300*57.3 = 17190 degrees

No. of rotation on the plane = 17190/360 = 47.75

I wrote a radtodeg function :

```
radtodeg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}                          
radtodeg(300)
```

How should I round off a degree equivalent to 17190 between 0 to 360.

Anyone with the round off function, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulus operator `%%` in your function if you want the answer to be modulo 360 (i.e. always between 0 and 360)

```
radtodeg <- function(rad) {((rad * 180) / (pi)) %% 360}

radtodeg(pi)
#> [1] 180

radtodeg(2 * pi)
#> [1] 0

radtodeg(3 * pi)
#> [1] 180

radtodeg(17190)
#> [1] 314.4498
```

Comment: Hey, Allan. So, I wanted to convert 300 radians to degrees and just wanted it to round of to a value between 0-360.

Comment: @InVinci so do `radtodeg(300)` using my function. If you want it as a whole number, do `round(radtodeg(300))`